# By Left shifting, can a number be set to ZERO

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I have a doubt in Left Shift Operator

```
int i = 1;
i <<= (sizeof (int) *8);
cout << i;
```

It prints 1.

1. i has been initialized to 1.
2. And while moving the bits till the size of the integer, it fills the LSB with 0's and as 1 crosses the limit of integer, i was expecting the output to be 0.

How and Why it is 1?

Comment: What if you `<<8` separately `sizeof (int)` times?

Comment: strange that compiler did not warn you

Comment: @triclosan: True. `g++` warns even without any extra warn-level. You have to shut it up forcibly with `-w` to keep it from warning.

Comment: `i = (int)((((unsigned int)i) << (sizeof(int)*4)) << (sizeof(int)*4))` works whenever `sizeof(unsigned int) <= sizeof(int)`. But why not just write `int i = 0;` in the first place?

Answer (score 14):

Let's say `sizeof(int)` is 4 on your platform. Then the expression becomes:

```
i = i << 32;
```

The standard says:

> 6.5.7-3
>
> If the value of the right operand is negative or is **greater than or
>   equal to the width of the promoted left operand**, the behavior is
>   undeﬁned.

Comment: try avoiding undefined behaviors!!

Comment: Which standard? The question is tagged c and c++.

Comment: @bitmask I was referring to the C99 standard. I guess my brain must have filtered out the `C++` tag and the `cout` :-?

Comment: Lets say sizeof (int) is 4
I redo the same operation as:
    i <<= 30;
    i <<= 1;
    i <<= 1;
Due to statement 1, the value in bit becomes 0100 0000 ... (24 0's)
Then by statement 2, it gets shifted left by 1 and turnes as negative number. And i expected the bit to be as 1000 0000 ... (24 0's)
So as per the previous one, i was expecting the next statement to be 0 on left shifting by 1.

Comment: @SivaSu Read my comment to bitmasks answer. Shifting signed stuff is a nasty business.

Comment: @bitmask, doesn't really matter, C++ (5.8/1 in C++2011) has the same constraint.

Answer (score 3):

As [cnicutar said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9429228/430766), your example exhibits undefined behaviour. That means that the compiler is free to do whatever the vendor seems fit, including [making demons fly out your nose](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html) or just doing nothing to the value at hand.

What you *can* do to convince yourself, that left shifting by the number of bits will produce `0` is this:

```
int i = 1;
i <<= (sizeof (int) *4);
i <<= (sizeof (int) *4);
cout << i;
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is right, since `i` is signed. Consider this: *If E1 has a signed type and nonnegative value and **`E1 x 2^E2 is` representable in the result type**, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undeﬁned.* Now your example clearly produces `2^32` which is not representable in an `int`.

Comment: @cnicutar: Yes, the output is undefined by the standard, just like the OP. However, while leaving the proper domain of C++, it will produce `0` on any implementation I know (although I hate "it works on my machine" arguments: http://ideone.com/tMDVl ... against my better judgement).

Comment: One cause of problem is that if shifting change the sign bit (and historically, in some machines -- the one I can think of were sign and magnitude -- the sign bit doesn't take part of shift) you won't get `E1 x 2^E2`. My guess is that it is UB instead of just unspecified so that compilers don't have to protect against trap values -- something rare nowadays.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9429228/968261)...

On the x86 platform your code would get compiled down to something like this:

```
; 32-bit ints:
mov cl, 32
shl dword ptr i, cl
```

The CPU will shift the dword in the variable `i` by the value contained in the `cl` register modulo 32. So, 32 modulo 32 yields 0. Hence, the shift doesn't really occur. And that's perfectly fine per the C standard. In fact, what the C standard says in 6.5.7-3 is because the aforementioned CPU behavior was quite common back in the day and influenced the standard.

Comment: Are you sure about the 16-bit shift?

Comment: @Atom: I've forgotten about it, you're right, it will shift a 16-bit word by up to 31 positions too. I'll remove the 16-bit case.

Comment: I tested what you mentioned as:
i <<= 30;
i <<= 2;
It gives the expected output as 0.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned by others, according to C standard the behavior of the shift is undefined.

That said, the program prints 1. A low-level explanation of why it prints 1 is as follows:

When compiling without optimizations the compiler (GCC, clang) emits the `SHL` instruction:

```
...
mov    $32,%ecx
shll   %cl,0x1c(%esp)
...
```

The Intel documentation for `SHL` instruction says:

> **SAL/SAR/SHL/SHR—Shift**
>
> The count is masked to 5 bits (or 6 bits if in 64-bit mode and REX.W is used). The count range is limited to 0 to 31 (or 63 if 64-bit mode and REX.W is used).

Masking the shift count 32 (binary 00100000) to 5 bits yields 0 (binary 00000000). Therefore the `shll   %cl,0x1c(%esp)` instruction isn't doing any shifting and leaves the value of `i` unchanged.

Comment: And one reason for the UB is that Intel did *not* say that for the  8086. That processor performed all the shifts you asked it to, and produced a zero for shifting more than the word size.